# js visualization - which technologies are used for this price chart?

Tags: javascript, css

Anybody has an idea how this price graph of the historical data is generated?

http://www.taskrabbit.com/tags/other_pickup_drop_off/in/all

I know that there are some JS libraries like http://raphaeljs.com/ that generate visualizations, but I am not really familiar with JS, so any hints are appreciated since I want to create a similiar visualization.

Comment: you want just the static graphs or some animation with it?

Comment: btw: don't understand the downvote. The answers could generate a useful list of resources or tips, how one can generate this kind of charts.

Comment: I have given a sample site where they show some types of easy-to-customize charts. Please rate me if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This website has a static [Chart](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_to_jquery_visualize_accessible_charts_with_html5_from_designing_with) and also they explain some vital jQuery methods that are essential for the displaying of chart and also you can download the code & it shouldn't be tough to customize yourself. I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, this definitely helps.